# I have a problem where my onclick only work once

Tags: reactjs

```
const UseStateObject = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    name: "SMK Kristen Immanuel Pontianak",
    message: "SMK bisa SMK hebat",
  });
  const [button, setButton] = useState({
    btn: "Kelasku",
  });
  const changeMessage = () => {
    setPerson({ ...person, message: "Kelas XI TKJ 2" });
    setButton({ ...button, btn: "Motto SMK" });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="borderbr">
        <h1 className="nama">{person.name}</h1>
        <h4 className="motto">{person.message}</h4>
        <button className="tombol" onClick={changeMessage}>
          {button.btn}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseStateObject;
```

this is my code and I have a problem where I can change the motto to Kelas XI TKJ 2 but I can't change it back to motto

Comment: your code always tries to change persn to **Kelas XI TKJ2** and button to **Motto SMK** you did not write any code to change it back, so its working as it is supposed to.

Comment: i see, what should i add to change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have code to swap the values always, you are alwys setting it to **Kelas XI TKJ 2**. If you want to toggle it for every click you can do something like this:

```
 const changeMessage = () => {
  setPerson((p) => ({
    ...p,
    message:
      p.message == "Kelas XI TKJ 2" ? "SMK bisa SMK hebat" : "Kelas XI TKJ 2",
  }));
  setButton((b) => ({
    btn: b.btn == "Kelasku" ? "Motto SMK" : "Kelasku",
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

as accepted answer works fine, but here is another method to get it done.

```
const changeMessage = () => {
setPerson({
  ...person,
  message:
    person.message === "Kelas XI TKJ 2"
      ? "SMK bisa SMK hebat"
      : "Kelas XI TKJ 2"
});
setButton({
  ...button,
  btn: button.btn === "Kelasku" ? "Motto SMK" : "Kelasku"
  });
};
```

here you can check working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-torvalds-6up51?file=/src/App.js:247-546)

Comment: Thank you for helping and this one works and pretty easy to read